# How to use CDN-JS library in TS-script on jsfiddle.net platform?

Tags: typescript, types, import, cdn, jsfiddle

For example, I have [sfiddle-example-js](https://jsfiddle.net/Artyom_Ionash/px913nja/49/) script like this and it works:

```js
const { parallelLimit } = async

new Promise(async () => {
  const tasks = Array(10)
    .fill(null)
    .map((item, i) => async () => i)
  const limit = 5
  await parallelLimit(tasks, limit)
    .then((results) => console.log(results.join(',')))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/3.2.3/async.js"></script>
```

But when I [switch it to TypeScript](https://jsfiddle.net/Artyom_Ionash/px913nja/66/), this script doesn't work.

Now I have to do something like this,

> npm i --save-dev @types/async

but how do I do it in the https://jsfiddle.net platform?